# xdebug.remote_autostart, remote, and connect_back not turning on

Tags: xdebug

I've spent some time trying to figure out why the autostart, remote , and connect_back settings wont turn on. I've typed in:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
;xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.108
```

All this into the php.ini file, restarted servers, and when I check the configuration page on the MAMP page, these settings still read OFF. Any idea why this is...

Comment: Is your xdebug extension loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late answer maybe but here's how I solved this issue.
For some reason MAMP conf files doesn't affect these settings, what I did was:

Go to /MAMP/bin/php/[phpX.X.XX ie your current version]/conf/php.ini and set it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is super late, but, you need to edit the correct php.ini file.  MAMP comes with 2 or more!

From the MAMP control/app launch the PHP_INFO() page, or make your own.  Check the path value for the `Loaded Configuration File`

That is the php.ini to edit.