# Eclipse XDebug stuck on 78%

Tags: eclipse, joomla, xdebug

i try to setup eclipse in order to debug my joomla web app.

I'm using MAMP on local machine, with php 5.6.10.

php.ini has these line:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

When try to start debug on Eclipse, the progress bar stuck on 78%:

> Waiting for XDebug.

How i can fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439881/xdebug-remote-autostart-remote-and-connect-back-not-turning-on ?

Comment: I have just tried this solution. Mamp read correctly this parameters but eclispe give me same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the remote host to

```
xdebug.remote_host=IP_ADDRESS
```

try to enable multihost debugging using this

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

Also check if your IDE is set in php.ini file

```
 xdebug.idekey=ECLIPSE_DBGP
```

For further help you can check this link https://xdebug.org/docs/remote