# Xdebug how accept all connections

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

How to debug all request (I used xDebug) to server without a parameter (XDEBUG_SESSION_START) or cookies. I want catch all request to a local server. This is need because I have a *.exe file which make a request to web-server and I can not understand a behavior my server.

Comment: in your settings, languages->PHP->Debug , make certain that Xdebug can accept external connexions is checked, and also check `detect path mappings`, and also have more than 1 simultaneous connexions (i use 8 typically), and also (Xdebug, check both `force break` setings). Finally, click on your `Start listening for Xdebug connexions` icon on the top menu bar.  That works for me all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I assume you might be looking for remote_autostart and remote_connect_back settings of XDebug.
Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439881/xdebug-remote-autostart-remote-and-connect-back-not-turning-on) for further references.